# What is different between Contextual Menu Button and Command Button in office ui fabric

Tags: office-ui-fabric

Contextual Menu Button and Command Button  looks like same in office ui fabric.what are the differences to use those button individually   ?
[Office ui fabric buttons](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fabric#/controls/web/button)

Answer (score 0):

Its mostly a styling difference. Command Buttons are used in our command bar. All buttons can accept menuProps and have a contextual menu.